# Present new VC when alertviewcontroller is open

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3

I want to display a new ViewController but it's not works when a AlertController is displayed. (I don't want use existing segue, only in swift). Somebody could help me ?
It's just a simple example, in my app i use a custom AlertController who display a loader. So, i don't want to be redirect after click in alert button

Thanks in advance

Ps: Sorry about my bad english.

```
@IBAction func testButtonClick(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "test", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    logout()
}

func logout() {
    let storyboardName = "Authentication"
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
    if let newVC = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() {
        newVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen
        self.present(newVC, animated: true)
    } else {
        print("Unable to instantiate VC from \(storyboardName) storyboard")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use in this way.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "test", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let newVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChildViewController") as? ChildViewController


        newVC?.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen

        presentedViewController?.present(newVC!, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is that you could keep the alert in a var at the instance level, so that as a pre-requisite to your transition, it first closes it.

```
var alert: UIAlertController?
```

In testButtonClick:

```
alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "test", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
let completion = { self.alert = nil }
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: completion)
```

In logout:

```
let completion = { self.alert = nil }
alert?.dismissViewController(animated: true, completion: completion)
```

Note: you can also make your life easy and use segues and `prepareForSegue`...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my problems is that i use this method (logout) in other class. In fact, I want to disconnect the user when there is an error on an http request. So I want to do something global. And this method (logout) is called automatically when there is an error. And I can make a request on any viewcontroller. So if I want to use the segues, I have to create one for each storyboard not?

Comment: That's something unwind segues can help with, I'd say. Also, maybe your app uses one (or more Router) for segues, which could centralize that logic.
Overall, it still seems to me that this method would work. Calling logout will close the AlertViewController if it exists, and not do it if it's nil.

Comment: Yes it works but I have to send the reference of the alertcontroller and my vc to class request. So I prefer the solution of Vinod Kumar. But thank you for your help